# how to convert a datetime ''Dec 25 2020 12:00AM" to this "2020-12-25 00:00:00.000" in SQL query

Tags: sql

how to convert a datetime ''Dec 25 2020 12:00AM" to this "2019-12-25 00:00:00.000" in SQL query

Comment: can any one please help me to resolve this?

Comment: `sql` is generic, Mention(tag) the SQL product exactly ex) MySQL, SQL Server etc.

Comment: Which implementation of SQL? This is not a standardized operation..

Comment: Use this function DATE_FORMAT(date, format) for MySql. For help with the format refer to - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code:

```
select cast('Dec 25 2020 12:00AM' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select convert( datetime,'Dec 25 2020 12:00AM')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Dec 25 2020 12:00AM')
```

This will give you the result